# Index out of bounds error when pulling an ArrayList into a 2D ArrayList of the same type

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have an array of html elements I am scraping that I need to add into a multi-dimensional arrayList to create a basic data table. Basically, I have a 221 x 12 element web table that I need to add in row by row (12 elements per row). I have a loop set up that locates every element by xpath in the row and then adds them in to an array called parser. Now, I need to add in parser to my multi-dimensional arrayList called data through every iteration of the loop. When I do this, I call a get and addAll, but I get an index out of bounds error.

My assumption is that I'm not initializing the row properly on the outer array, but I'm not sure how else to add in the inner array. I've tried deleting the get parameter, but when I do I get a type argument compilation error. I also tried initializing the outer array with a null value 1st, but this only filled the array with nulls.

I'll add that all the elements are strings, and this is the source if that's important for any reason (https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/). If multi-dimensional ArrayLists aren't the best approach I'm open to other options as well.

Here's what I have:

```java
public void elementLocator() {
  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
  try {
    String prefix = "//*[@id=\"main_table_countries_today\"]/tbody[1]/tr[";
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 222; i++) {
      try {
        ArrayList<String> parser = new ArrayList<String>();
        parser.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath(prefix + i + "]/td[1]")).getText());
        parser.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath(prefix + i + "]/td[2]")).getText());
        parser.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath(prefix + i + "]/td[3]")).getText());
        parser.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath(prefix + i + "]/td[4]")).getText());
        parser.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath(prefix + i + "]/td[5]")).getText());
        parser.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath(prefix + i + "]/td[6]")).getText());
        parser.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath(prefix + i + "]/td[7]")).getText());
        parser.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath(prefix + i + "]/td[8]")).getText());
        parser.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath(prefix + i + "]/td[9]")).getText());
        parser.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath(prefix + i + "]/td[10]")).getText());
        parser.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath(prefix + i + "]/td[11]")).getText());
        parser.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath(prefix + i + "]/td[12]")).getText());
        data.get(0).addAll(j, parser); //Runtime error here
        j++;
        System.out.println(j);
        //Skip blank rows
      } catch (Exception e) {
        j++;
        e.printStackTrace();;
        continue;
      }
      System.out.println(data);
    }
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    closeBrowser();
    //Catch specific exception for html element not found
  } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    System.out.println("Selected element not found");
    error = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call  `data.get(0)` but data is empty so you get OutOfBounds exception.

You need to add the array to data like this: `data.add(parser)`

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. I kept reading every resource I could find and never even thought about trying to add it like I would a single element. Thank you, upvoted and selected!

Comment: I wish you don't feel dumb. I want to ask you about your process. When you got this exception did you understood why you get it? If not, did you separate the line to 2 in order to understand which method call is causing it?

Answer (score 1):

Uh, I don't have enough reputation else I would have created a comment for such a simple suggestion. Also it does not answer the question because it was already done by shanif. You may short your code like this:

```
for(int j=1; j<=12; j++){
    parser.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath(prefix + i + "]/td["+j+"]")).getText());
}
```